# Azure AD reply url: how to add several urls when using openid connect auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to build a ASP.NET MVC app which doesn't allow access to anonymous user (with the exception of a custom URL that is to be shown to authenticated users which aren't allowed to use the app).

Now, I've register my app in the azure portal (portal.azure.com) and I'd like to use several URLs. I've added two entries:

1. https://localhost/test
2. https://www.test.com

I'm using the following code to configure authentication at startup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(
          CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
      new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {                                                                                        
          ClientId = clientId,                                                                                        
          Authority = authority,                                                                                        
          PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,                                                                                        
          Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
            SecurityTokenValidated = VerificaUtilizadorAutenticado,
            AuthenticationFailed = TrataErroAutenticacao
         }
     });
}
```

Everything seemed to be working fine, but after publishing the app, it seems like I can only use one of the URIs. I've searched and it seems like I can use the RedirectUri property of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions to set up the reply url. So, I've tried adding this to the setup:

```
RedirectUri = "https://localhost/test",
```

Unfortunately, doing that breaks everything and the browser gets stuck between my app and MS' login page. Since the user is logged in, it redirects the user back to my app. However, it seems like setting the RedirectUri prop does not generate the app's authentication cookie, so it sends the user back to the login page.

If I remove the RedirectUri, then I get redirected to the https://www.test.com site, even though I'm trying to access the https://localhost/test web app.

I'm not sure what, but I'm missing something...Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: Can you share the URL of the User's Login Screen. If you did things correctly, there should be a querystring parameter in that url like: `&redirect_uri=https://localhost/test`.

Comment: Hello Shawn. it's not being set. There's no redirect_uri parameter...

It seems like it will always redirect to the first url...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after some digging, I've noticed that the problem I was having when setting the redirecturi was that I was missing...a slash (/). So, adding the / to the URL defined on the portal and putting it also in the redirecturi of the options object was enough to make it work against different URI...

Comment: Do you mean a trailing slash i.e. https://www.example.com/authsite/  ? Right now for me it always redirects the user back to https://www.example.com/ (and ignores my application authsite)

Comment: Yes, I had to add the trailing slash (in your example, it would look like example.com/authsite/, where authsite would be the name of the app created in the default IIS web site)

Answer (score 9):

When you send a user who wants to sign in to the AAD Login Endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com`), you will need to specify where you want the user (and the Authorization Code) to be redirected back to.

You specify this in two ways:

1. You must configure a Reply URL in your app's main configuration as a part of app creation.
2. You must specify a Reply URL in your Login URL, which exactly matches one of the URLs you configured:

   From the [Authorization Code Grant Flow documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code):

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F   <-- this guy
   &response_mode=query
   &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
   &state=12345
   ```

If you do not specify a Redirect URI in your Login URL, the user will be redirected to the first URL specified in your app's registration. That doesn't sound so bad, but know that AAD treats your Reply URLs as an unordered list, so depending on the server you hit, or how data got replicated, you might observe different redirection behaviors across different sign-in attempts. That is why it is important to ALWAYS specify the `redirect_uri` parameter in your login endpoint.

I feel like many of your problems may be solved if you use the [ADAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to authenticate rather than the libraries shown in your sample code, but if you do not want to use these, then you will need to share more details like the HTTP trace of the authentication process.

Comment: Hello again Shawn. Thanks for the thorough reply. I agree with you, but if I do that (and I have tried) I get stuck between redirects (after logging in in azure ad, I get redirected to the homepage and I'm immediately redirected back to login page again - which returns me back to the site because I've already signed in before... And it goes on and on...). Regarding he code, it was generated automatically by vs when I connected the app to azure... I expected everything to work out well... But it seems like that's not the case...

Comment: Unfortunately based on the behavior alone, it is hard to debug your issue. The question I have are: "Are successfully getting the Auth Code? Are you successfully exchanging that Auth Code for an Access Token? Is that access token correctly being stored in your token cache? etc..." You are really depending a lot on the library here to do "the right thing", and not really investigating the individual steps which the library should be doing. I think that is where you need to start your investigation into the issue. Otherwise, use a known working sample [here](https://github.com/azure-samples).

Comment: Hello again Shawn. Yes, lots of things can go wrong. I think that the problem here is that the redirecturi should be handled internally my the pipeline middleware so that it generates the cookie used for authentication. When I set the redirecturi to the homepage, I do get redirected to my homepage, but since the user has only been authenticated by the external provider, there' s no auth cookie. So redirecting the user to the homepage means generating a new 401 challenge...I think I'll have to take a look at the source code to see what's going on here...

Comment: How can i specify redirect_uri dynamicly during request ? i need to redirect some of them to tenant1.test.com and some to tenant2.test.com. I think i need to modify request somehow and inject this redirect uri  but i could not find

Comment: You can add both reply urls to your applications configuration and then use your apps logic to modify the intended reply url. Before they start the log in process